# When using LibGdx openURI I get an error -12

Tags: java, libgdx, open-uri, clicklistener

I created a button with a ClickListener to link to a website, this is the bit of code:

```
buttonRight.addListener(new ClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
        Gdx.net.openURI("https://website/");
    }
});
```

nothing happens when clicked, log error is:

```
 E/IAudioFlinger: createTrack returned error -12
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Are you on the desktop, android, ios or html version ?

Comment: I'm using android

Comment: It seems that the `createTrack` method of [AudioFlinger](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/master/services/audioflinger/AudioFlinger.cpp#742) (starting on line 742) has various reasons to return the same error code. Is this the whole error / stack trace? The errors seem to be logged in AudioFlinger (e.g. in line [793](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/master/services/audioflinger/AudioFlinger.cpp#793). If you can find the logs that might be a hint what the root cause of the problem is.

Comment: I added a log print now, it doesn't print to the log. Seems like it's not registering being clicked